# Installing ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty" – apt-get unable to locate "ros-indigo-desktop-full"

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

NOTE: I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I followed the instructions on the wiki page pertaining to the installation of Indigo until part 1.4, but when I type in `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

The same thing happens with the other default packages, and the results `apt-cache search ros-indigo` do not contain any of them, either. I ran `sudo apt-get update`, set up my keys, ran the software updater, restarted and everything, but the problem hasn't been resolved. What am I supposed to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155241/installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04-lts-%22trusty%22-%E2%80%93-apt-get-unable-to-locate-%22ros-indigo-desktop-full%22/) by [MekBoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/15006/mekboy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-20**:
The reason is that it is probably not released, yet.

**Comment by [MekBoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/15006/mekboy/) on 2014-04-20**:
Then why do they have installation instructions on the wiki? Also, "apt-cache search ros-indigo" returns a large amount of packages related to the release, just none of the defaults.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-20**:
I guess once it's released, the desktop-full packages will be there. If you want an actual answer as to why that is, wait for someone official. The Indigo website says: "This ROS distribution is under development and not yet released. Please use the latest officially released distribution: Hydro."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo for Trusty is not yet released, not all package binaries are there yet.

http://answers.ros.org/question/154806/indigo-on-trusty/

You can compile ros_comm for now from source and install all ros-indigo-* packages from apt-get, this gives sufficient ROS functionality for me at least.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2015-09-11**:
Is Indigo for Trusty released yet? I still can't get this to work.